# Retrieve IBM i column headings from SQL using pyodbc

Tags: python, db2, pyodbc, db2-400

I want to launch SQL querys from a PC to a DB2-database on IBM i.
The files were created with the old method (source file, 10-character's file and field name, and detailled column-heading)
In SQL from the emulator, I have an option to retrieve the column headings with the long name (Preferences / Results / column headings), so I think the jdbc driver can export them (I think it is allowed when checking Edition / JDBC Configuration/ Other / Extended metadata).

I can't retrieve this long name column heading when using pyodbc from python, using the driver "iSeries Access ODBC Driver". I don't see where tohave it, I searched in https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=apis-connection-string-keywords the right option for the connection string, but did'nt find anything.
The 'description' cursor attribute in pyodbc does retrieve the column name and length, but no extended attribute

Is this not possible at all to retrieve the long name? Is this option accessible in the jdbc driver?

Comment: Try tracing the jdbc driver to see what it is doing under the cover (i.e. whether it is using specific keywords/attributes) to see if there is a matching equivalent for the odbc driver.

Comment: Given that you tables are defined with DDS source, Are you sure they have long column names? I am pretty sure that they do not have long table names. Column headings and text are not long column names.

Comment: A suggestion: Post the results you get when you select the 'long name column heading' option. Also DSPFFD to see how the table is currently defined - it might be different to the DDS because SQL ALTER TABLE can be done to any table.

Comment: Isn't EXTCOLINFO (SQL_DESC_LABEL) in *Performance properties* what you want ? (btw see [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=details-connection-string-keywords) for a page that's up to date)

Comment: @nfgl Yes, I think it's what I need! Thanks for the updated page. My problem now is that it seems pyodbc doesn't return anything different when positionning extended column information to 1. Nothing new in cursor.description

Comment: Yes, can't find a way. if jaydebeapi is an option for you, `cursor._meta.getColumnLabel(n)` returns COLHDG when `extended metadata=true`

Comment: Thanks, that did it, with jdbc and jaydebeapi.
Can you change your comment to an answer, so that I can mark it as the  accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple working example of what I needed, based on nfgl's comments

```
# With JayDeBeApi :
#   pip install JayDeBeApi
# And jdbc Driver :
#   JTOPEN in https://sourceforge.net/projects/jt400/
#          Copy the file jt400.jar in this directory

import os
import jaydebeapi


def run_sql(sql):

    # Create a jdbc connexion
    # Connexion string  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=details-connection-string-keywords           
    system   = 'MYAS400'
    username = 'MYNAME'
    password = 'MYPSW'
    connection_string='jdbc:as400://' + system
    driver_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) , "jt400.jar")
    cnxn = jaydebeapi.connect("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver",
                          connection_string,
                          {'user':username, 'password':password, 'extended metadata': 'true'},
                          driver_file_path )
    with cnxn:
        # Create a cursor
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)

        if cursor.description != None:
            header = tuple((cursor._meta.getColumnLabel(i+1)) for i in range(len(cursor.description)))
            print(header)
            print ('*' * 100)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            while result != None:
                print(result)
                result = cursor.fetchone()


def main():

    run_sql("SELECT x, y, z, 'A' as \"New Column\" FROM mylib.mytable WHERE thefield = 'OK'" )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a number of things you could be talking about, so I will cover them all in this answer.

But for the record, you should be able to retrieve all names/comments/labels from the QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS catalog view.

Now what are the names/comments/labels?

**First the field names:** There are two of these, in the system catalog, they are referred to as COLUMN_NAME and SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME. The SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME is the 10 character IBM i DDS name for the field. If a longer name is defined for the column, that will be in COLUMN_NAME, otherwise the 10 character name will be in COLUMN_NAME as well. These two values are defined in different ways depending on whether you are defining the file using SQL or DDS to create the file. For DDS, the default name is the SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME, and if you want to define a long column name you can use the ALIAS keyword. This is usually not done, so DDS defined files on IBM i generally do not have a long name, thus typically for DDS defined files, SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME and COLUMN_NAME are the same.

For SQL defined tables, the name can be up to 128 characters in length, and is stored in COLUMN_NAME. If the COLUMN_NAME is over 10 characters, you can also specify a system name by using `FOR` like this `THIS_IS_A_LONG_NAME for SHORTNM char(10)`. In this case `THIS_IS_A_LONG_NAME` is the COLUMN_NAME, and SHORTNM is the SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME. One key rule though: If COLUMN_NAME is 10 characters or less, you cannot specify a SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME.

Note, JDBC uses COLUMN_NAME which is the long name, so when you retrieve column attributes using JDBC, you are getting the long name. I don't believe you can retrieve the short field name other than by querying the catalog view.

**Second the labels:** There are two different kinds of labels you can apply to a field using the SQL LABEL statement, Column Headings, and Field Text. These can also be added using DDS, and it is common for both to be present in DDS defined tables. The DDS keywords here are `COLHDG` and `TEXT`. Column Heading is a strange field. You can specify 3 lines of 20 characters for the column heading. It appears in the catalog view as a single 60 character field named COLUMN_HEADING where the first 20 characters is the first line, the next 20 characters is the second line, and the last 20 characters is the third line. The field text, or sometimes called the field description is 50 character value specified with the `TEXT` keyword. This appears in the COLUMN_TEXT field of the catalog view.

In SQL, both of these catalog view fields are populated with the `LABEL ON` statement. To populate the column heading, the syntax is:

```
LABEL ON COLUMN column_name IS label;
```

To populate the column text, the syntax is:

```
LABEL ON COLUMN column_name TEXT IS label;
```

I believe the only way to retrieve either of these values in JDBC is to query the catalog view.

**Finally the comment:** There is a 2000 character LONG_COMMENT field in the catalog view that can be populated only by SQL. Files defined using DDS will not have this field populated unless it was added using SQL as there is no applicable DDS keyword. In SQL you would use:

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN column_name IS comment;
```

Once again, the only way to retrieve this using JDBC is to query the catalog view.

Comment: What I need is the information I get with "run sql script"  in IBM i Access Client Solutions.
It is the column heading,  created with COLHDG, the exact same column heading given by RUNQRY, it is the field COLUMN_HEADING from qsys2.syscolumns.

Comment: Then I believe that you need to Query qsys2.syscolumns for that info. ODBC does not return that value in it's SQLCOLUMNS schema.